# Replace the vb scripting with Javascript for compatibility in all browsers

Tags: javascript, html, vbscript, dom-events

I'm trying to convert vbscript function in Javascript  in html files for opening link in the same page.  I'm  using the following code in vbscript:

```
 <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
 Sub clickHandler()
    sP = Window.Event.SrcElement.ID
    If Left(sP, 1) = "M" Then
        Set oC = Document.All("C" & Mid(sP, 2))
        If oC.Style.Display = "none" Then
            oC.Style.Display = ""
         Else
            oC.Style.Display = "none"
        End If
        Set oC = Nothing
      End If
  End Sub
```

What are the alternative methods in Javascript? Please suggest something or any online help to convert the vbscript code into Javascript.

Comment: Check into this : http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=6675&lngWId=14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function clickHandler(e)
{
  var sP=(e?(e.target || e.srcElement):window.event.srcElement).id;
  if(sP[0]=="M")
  {
    var oC=document.getElementById("C"+sP.substr(1));
    if(oC.style.display=="none") oC.style.display="";
    else oC.style.display="none";
  }
}
```

Note that you'll also have to register event handler this way:

```
<button id="M78" onclick="clickHandler(event);">Whatever</button>
```

Comment: internet explorer supporting this but google chrome not supporting this can you suggest me any help

Comment: @user1865365 Works for me in Chrome and all other browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/K4xFb/

Comment: shoswing error in  if(oC.style.display=="none") oC.style.display="";
    else oC.style.display="none"; in chrome

Comment: @user1865365 Do you have an element with the corresponding ID?

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0)"><u><b><span id=M26>2012-2013</span></b></u> <div id=c26 STYLE="display:none">

Comment: `sP[0]` is not support in all browsers. Use `sP.charAt(0)`. Also, if you use `document.getElementById('M78').onclick = clickHandler;` there is no need to explicitly pass in any parameter. Then also, you can use `this` instead of having to deal with `srcElement`. Next, `substr` is not supported in all browsers, use `substring` instead. Last, best practice is to use `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: @ErikE About the event thing, I'm just following OP's style, also, `JS:element.onclick` will be inconvenience if OP has various length elements and/or he's generating these elements dynamically via server script; About `substr`, I'm really curious which browser doesn't support it. MDN only hints that old IE doesn't support negative position; About the `===`, I have to admit I've never heard of it, I only use it when it _has to_ (e.g. to avoid `0==false`). My fiddle even works in IE8, and I think that's acceptable to most people.